# Cleaned value of the field not shown in the form's input (only old value is displayed)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
class SourceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Source
        widgets = {
            'category_re': forms.TextInput(),
            'thumb_re': forms.TextInput(),
            'movie_re': forms.TextInput()
        }

    def clean_url(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['url']
        return helpers.url_fix(data)
```

and the following view:

```
def source_form(request, id):
    source = get_object_or_404(Source, pk=id)
    form = SourceForm(request.POST or None, instance=source)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    return render_to_response('source/form.html', {'form': form, 'source': source},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And I have the problem. Cleaned value of `url` field don't shown in the form. I see only old, not modified value, but then I try to add `{{ form.cleaned_data }}` in the template - it shows right value. Why it happened so? How can I fix it?

TIA!

Comment: try: `if self.is_valid: data = self.cleaned_data['url']` in `clean_url`

Comment: thx for answer! it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `form` is using the `request.POST` data and not the `cleaned_data`.  Try reassigning your `form` variable after your `save()`:

```
def source_form(request, id):
    source = get_object_or_404(Source, pk=id)
    form = SourceForm(request.POST or None, instance=source)

    if form.is_valid():
        source = form.save()
        form = SourceForm(instance=source)

    return render_to_response('source/form.html', {'form': form, 'source': source},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: @dizpers Also, you don't have to pass `source` to your template context as you can access it through `form.instance`